# plupload2 image preview

Tags: javascript, image, plupload

I am implementing a custom plupload uploader and wanted to include image previews before the image is uploaded to the server. How do I access the file? I plan to do this at the FilesAdded event as shown in the code snippet below:

```
uploader.bind('FilesAdded',function(up,files){
$('#filelist').append('<img src=" "/>'); //render image preview here
}
```

I am currently able to display other information such as image filename, size, etc. However, I don't know about the image preview.